# How to checked check box values with existing comma separated values stored in DB using Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I shows amenities  checkbox options as ng-repeat of  a json array and i stored into database as comma separated ids like "1,3,7"  as a single string but when i need to edit amenities  checkbox  i am unable to show existing options as checked because i get existing value from  db as 1,3,7 as single string how i will check this string with options in the ng-repeat ?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.amenities=[{id:1,value:"Wifi"},
                  {id:2,value:"AC"},
                  {id:3,value:"Creditcard"},
                  {id:4,value:"24x7"},
                  {id:5,value:"Parking"},
                  {id:6,value:"Free delivery"},
                  {id:7,value:"No Smoking"}
                 ];

     //For example  assume that this is existing amenities from database
     $scope.existamenities="1,3,7";            
});

</script>

<htmL>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="amn in amenities"> 
  <label>{{amn.value}}
<input type="checkbox"  name="amenities"   ng-value="amn.id">
</label>
</div>



</div>

</htmL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe for them to be checked you need to set the `ng-model` to true or false. Simply create another array and populate it accordingly.

You have an option to append the existing array with new properties that will hold true/false values, or create a new array that was mapped from the original one. Then simply switch default `false` values to `true` **if** their ID is listed, which you can get by splitting the string.

Here is a small demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.amenities = [
    {id:1,value:"Wifi"},
    {id:2,value:"AC"},
    {id:3,value:"Creditcard"},
    {id:4,value:"24x7"},
    {id:5,value:"Parking"},
    {id:6,value:"Free delivery"},
    {id:7,value:"No Smoking"}
  ];

  //For example  assume that this is existing amenities from database
  $scope.existamenities = "1,3,7";

  var a = $scope.existamenities.split(",").map(x => Number(x))
  var b = $scope.amenities.map((x) => {
    return {
      "id": x.id,
      "val": false
    }
  })
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (b[i].id == a[j]) {
        b[i].val = true
      }
    }
  }
  $scope.model = b;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="amn in amenities">
    <label>{{amn.value}}
<input type="checkbox"  name="amenities"  ng-model="model[$index].val" ng-value="amn.id">
</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi , I have   one  query for you ,that is  if i use  $scope.existamenities = ["1","3","7"];  then how i will re arrange the above js code.I have tried this code by with out  split(",")  for this case by nothing happening  there.Please  help me

Comment: Please check this link https://plnkr.co/edit/JYWH22EYYhDqcJPgx9Pi?p=preview

Comment: @SherinGreen just **don't split**, if it's already an array. Change `.split(",").map(x => Number(x))` to `.map(x => Number(x))`

Comment: Could you please help me on this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356472/how-to-validate-a-input-box-in-angular-js-which-name-is-array-of-name-like-ite

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ng-model` on each checkbox in order to be able to control if they're checked or not ... and be able to tell which ones are checked at a later point, e.g. form submission.

In order to do that:

- Amenities objects should have a `checked` property
- The checkboxes in the `ng-repeat` should bind `ng-model` to the `checked` property

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.amenities=[{id:1,value:"Wifi", checked: false},
                  {id:2,value:"AC", checked: false},
                  {id:3,value:"Creditcard", checked: false},
                  {id:4,value:"24x7", checked: false},
                  {id:5,value:"Parking", checked: false},
                  {id:6,value:"Free delivery", checked: false},
                  {id:7,value:"No Smoking", checked: false}
                 ];

     //For example  assume that this is existing amenities from database
     $scope.existamenities="1,3,7";            

     var arrayOfExistingAmenities = $scope.existamenities.split(",");
     arrayOfExistingAmenities.forEach(function(existingAmenity) {
        $scope.amenities.forEach(function(amenity) {
            if (amenity.id == parseInt(existingAmenity)) {
                amenity.checked = true;
            }
        });
     });


});

</script>

<htmL>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="amn in amenities"> 
  <label>{{amn.value}}
<input type="checkbox"  name="amenities" ng-model="amn.checked"  ng-value="amn.id">
</label>
</div>



</div>

</htmL>
```