# How to validate a input box in Angular js ,which name is array of name like 'item[priceFrom]'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

How to validate a input text box as number,I  use ng-pattern for validate number but my input name is array of name  like "item[priceFrom]"  so  how will i validate this field.This validation is working fine if  input name is "priceFrom".

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    //$scope.name = "John Doe";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form  name="myForm"  class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="">
        
        <div class="input-field">
            <p class="heading">Price</p>
            <div class="gutter6">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="input-wrapper has-float-label">
                        <input   ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-model="search.priceFrom" type="text" id="price" name="item[priceFrom]" class="form-field">
                        <label  class="form-control-placeholder ">From</label>
                    </div>
                    <span ng-show="myForm.item[priceFrom].$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <input  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"  ng-model="search.priceTo" type="text" id="price" name="item[priceTo]" class="form-field" value="">
                        <label  class="form-control-placeholder">To</label>
                    </div>
                    <span ng-show="myForm.item[priceTo].$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center" style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <input class="button submit esein5" value="Apply" type="submit">
            <button type="Reset" class="button submit esein5">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: that's a wrong syntax. Change `item[priceFrom]` to `priceFrom`. Note that it's just a string. If you are planning on using some variables from the controller, then it would be `name="{{item[priceFrom]}}"`, but that's not recommended

Comment: that is not possible in my application  because in server side  i take values as $_GET  that's why i use  'item[priceFrom]'  so can we validate input by ng-model instead of input name?

Comment: don't use `method="get"`, change it to `<form name="myForm"  ng-submit="submit()">` and then call your backend from the controller: `$scope.submit = function(){ $http.post("some_url.php", data).then(...) }` and receive it as: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: Actually this is used  for filter functions so i need to   pass   multiple items with url  and form is submit through php so angular js is  only used  for validation in here.So is any  solution for  <span ng-show="myForm.item[priceTo].$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span> this

Comment: Then try writing `myForm.item[priceFrom].$error.pattern` as `myForm['item[priceFrom]'].$error.pattern`

Comment: Hi,This is working fine.Please answer my question with  this above code.So  it will help to some one.Thanks  Very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176052/discussion-between-sherin-green-and-aleksey-solovey).

Answer (score 0):

Answer courtesy :Aleksey Solovey
https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495123/aleksey-solovey

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    //$scope.name = "John Doe";
});
```

```css
.error{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form  name="myForm"  class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="">
        
        <div class="input-field">
            <p class="heading">Price</p>
            <div class="gutter6">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="input-wrapper has-float-label">
                        <input   ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-model="search.priceFrom" type="text" id="price" name="item[priceFrom]" class="form-field">
                        <label  class="form-control-placeholder ">From</label>
                    </div>
                    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm['item[priceFrom]'].$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <input  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"  ng-model="search.priceTo" type="text" id="price" name="item[priceTo]" class="form-field" value="">
                        <label  class="form-control-placeholder">To</label>
                    </div>
                    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm['item[priceTo]'].$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center" style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <input class="button submit esein5" value="Apply" type="submit">
            <button type="Reset" class="button submit esein5">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```